Streamlit Aggrid - range selection only in one column
I am able to select a range with gb.configure_grid_options(enableRangeSelection=True).
However I need range selection only in one column (say column “Name”) and not the others.
Please guide how can I achieve this.
My current script looks like this…
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder

# Create a small sample dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
        "Age": [25, 30, 22],
        "Salary": [50000, 60000, 55000],
    }
)

gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)

gb.configure_grid_options(enableRangeSelection=True)

gridOptions = gb.build()

# Display the dataframe using AG Grid
AgGrid(data, height=400, gridOptions=gridOptions, key="a")


You can pick this JavaScript func (made by @dwsndev) and inject it with AgGrid :
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder, JsCode

usecols = ["Name"] # << add more if needed

jscode = JsCode(
    """
    function onRangeSelectionChanged(event) {
    // Must match 'field' property of columns.
    const enabledRangeColumns = new Set(%s);
    const [range] = event.api.getCellRanges();

    if (range && !enabledRangeColumns.has(range.startColumn.getColId())) {
        event.api.clearRangeSelection();
    }
}
"""
    % usecols
)

gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)

gb.configure_grid_options(
    enableRangeSelection=True,
    onRangeSelectionChanged=jscode,
)

AgGrid(
    data,
    height=150,
    gridOptions=gb.build(),
    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
    key="a",
)


